# using single field for IN out tinme in table

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, sql-server-2008

we have a bio metric software for attendance, you press finger over sensor and it puts you IN/OUT time in SQL database, it's desktop app but boss asked me to make same but Web Application in asp.net MVC, now we have 2 tables

```
tblEmployee

SerialId
EmpId
EmpName
DepId




tblAttendance


AtdId
EmpId (FK)
Time(IN/OUT)
Date
```

now problem is that When i come into office then it put new record in attendance table and when i leave office then it again put whole record for OUT time in attendance table, it's using same field TIME for IN and OUT both. So thinking to solve this issue like Keeping single record for single day and only changing IN/OUT time ?

Answer (score 0):

This look like normal behavior to me, but still if you want to achive what you have asked, you could change the table definition like this -

```
tblAttendance

AtdId
EmpId (FK)
Date --Just the date for every day
Time_IN
Time_OUT
```

Now you need to figure out which swipe it is - IN or OUT and update the particular value. For every IN there would be a new row - which you can control for a particular DATE - as in one row per DATE - **Composite Primary Key** - AtdId, EmpId (FK), Date

**Note** - Over the time the above approach will slow down the punch IN/punch OUT process. It'll take comparatively longer to register the swipes. Your current DB structure is more apt for long term usage. If you want to display the data in any particular format, you should rather design views as per your requirements.

Comment: @James - As per the existing design in your question, every IN/OUT will simply **INSERT** a new record - it doesn't have to **seek** anything. But as per the changed approach which I've told in my answer, you'll have to seek for every IN/OUT - check if this is the first IN for the day and then INSERT, or if one IN for the day has already been done, then UPDATE. **This seek & update will consume more time (as compared to simple INSERT) when your data grows.**